# Create RavenDB reference field without linking to Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, ravendb

I am storing an object in RavenDB that has a reference to another object.  I wish to indicate to the RavenDB serializer that it should be a reference, not an embedded object.  The way to do this is to decorate it with `[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` attribute.  This is fine, however it means that I have to reference the `Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json` assembly in my POCO assembly.

So the question is, is there another way to apply this attribute?  Perhaps using `DefaultContractResolver` somehow?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle that using a contract resolver yes. You can customize the contract resolvers in the RavenDB Conventions.